# Разобрать строку по разделителям

Tags: sql, sql-server, строки, оптимизация

Необходимо разобрать строку:

> '1-1,2;2-1,2;3-1,2,3'

И поместить во временную таблицу в виде:

> id|N
>   1|1
>   1|2
>   2|1
>   2|2
>   3|1
>   3|2
>   3|3

Я попытался разобрать таким образом:

```
declare @i1   int
      , @i2   int
      , @s    varchar(255)
      , @text varchar(255) = '10-10,20;20-11,21;30-12,22,32'
      , @c    varchar(120)
      , @id   varchar(50)
      , @ln   int
      , @curr int

declare @t table([name] varchar(120))
declare @r table([id] varchar(120), [N] varchar(120))

set @i2 = 1

while @i2 > 0
    begin
        set @i1 = charindex(';', @text, @i2)  -- поиск запятой с позиции @i2
        if @i1 > 0
            begin                    -- запятая найдена в позиции @i1
                set @s = substring(@text, @i2, @i1-@i2)
                set @i2 = @i1 + 1
            end
            else
            begin                        -- запятой нет
                set @s = substring(@text, @i2, len(@text)-@i2+1)
                set @i2 = 0
            end
        insert into @t select @s
    end

declare cur cursor
for select [name] from @t

open cur

fetch next from cur into @c

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        -- найти заголовок
        select @ln = charindex('-', @c)
        select @id = left(@c, @ln - 1)
        -- прочитать данные
        while len(@c) > @ln + 1
              and @ln != 0
            begin
                select @curr = charindex(',', @c, @ln+1)
                if @curr = 0
                    begin
                        insert into @r ([id], [N])values(@id, substring(@c, @ln+1, len(@c)-@ln))
                        break
                    end
                    else
                        insert into @r ([id], [N])values(@id, substring(@c, @ln+1, @curr-@ln-1))
                set @ln = @curr
            end
        fetch next from cur into @c
    end

close cur

deallocate cur

select * from @t    
select * from @r
```

Заметил, что если использовать строку '1-1,2;2-1,2;3-1,2,3', то запрос отрабатывает не корректно.
Помогите оптимизировать(переписать, ускорить) запрос!

Answer (score 1):

Язык SQL в основе своей декларативный, и хотя императивные инструкции в T-SQL присутствуют в достаточной мере, их производительность при интенсивном использовании, как правило, оставляет желать лучшего. Избегайте использования курсоров и циклов там, где без них можно обойтись.

В SqlServer 2016 (и более поздних версиях) можно воспользоваться функцией [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql):

```
declare @str varchar(8000) = '1-1,2;2-1,2;3-1,2,3';

SELECT
    Id = CONVERT(int, LEFT(a.value, CHARINDEX('-', a.value) - 1)),
    N = CONVERT(int, b.value)
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT(@str, ';') a
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(a.value, CHARINDEX('-', a.value) + 1, 8000), ',') b
```

В SqlServer 2014 (и более ранних версиях) можно воспользоваться одной из существующих реализаций в виде встраиваемой табличной функции. Я бы порекомендовал *DelimitedSplit8K* от Jeff Moden ([здесь](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)), которая адаптируется совершенно аналогично:

```
SELECT
    Id = CONVERT(int, LEFT(a.Item, CHARINDEX('-', a.Item) - 1)),
    N = CONVERT(int, b.Item)
FROM
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str, ';') a
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(SUBSTRING(a.Item, CHARINDEX('-', a.Item) + 1, 8000), ',') b
```

Или одну из CLR-реализаций, например *Split* в составе библиотеки SQL# ([здесь](https://sqlsharp.com/features/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @text varchar(255) = '1-1,2;2-1,2;3-1,2,3'
declare @id   int
declare @lines table([line] varchar(120))
declare @row varchar(255)
declare @separatorIndex int
declare @values table([id] int, [value] varchar(120))

insert into @lines 
select * from [dbo].[SplitString](@text, ';')

While (Select Count(*) From @lines) > 0
Begin
    set @row = (Select Top 1 line From @lines)
    set @separatorIndex = (select CHARINDEX('-', @row))
    set @id = (select LEFT(@row, @separatorIndex - 1))

    insert into @values (id, value)
    select @id, Value from [dbo].[SplitString](SUBSTRING(@row, @separatorIndex + 1 , LEN(@row)), ',')

    Delete @lines Where line = @row
End

select * from @values
```

разделяем текст на строки, с левой части берем id, справа разделяем на значения и создаем новую таблицу.

функцию `SplitString` брал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19935594/3373603)

Результат:

```
id  value
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
```